# Django, checkbox add goods to cart with size that user choose by click checkbox

Tags: django, checkbox

Good day to all.

Please don't judge strictly, I'm just learning. I started learning Django and everything seemed to be going smoothly until I ran into the problem of adding an item to the cart along with the size. There is no problem adding the product itself, but I need the user to select the size through a checkbox and after clicking on the “add to cart” button, not just a product will be added to it, but with the desired selected size.

Here are the product models, sizes and carts

```
class Product(models.Model):
    article = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,blank=False,unique=True,primary_key=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,blank=False)
    is_child = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=24,null=False)
    sizes = models.ForeignKey(to='Size',on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article')
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.article}"
 
 
class Size(models.Model):
    article = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,unique=True)
    article_size = models.ForeignKey(to='ArticleSize',on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article_size')
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.article}"
 
class ArticleSize(models.Model):
    article_size = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, unique=True)
    size_name = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,blank=False)
    qty = models.SmallIntegerField()
    to_article = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.article_size}"
 
class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article')
    size = models.ForeignKey(to=ArticleSize,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article_size')
    qty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    create_time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Корзина для {self.user.email} товар {self.product.article},размер {self.size.size_name}"
```

Here is the form model:

```
class CheckboxForm(forms.Form):
    checkbox_size = forms.CharField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
    'class':'size_checkbox', 'type':'checkbox', 'name':'size_checkbox'}),required=True)
 
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleSize
        fields = ('checkbox_size')
```

Here is the view:

```
def products(request):
    form = CheckboxForm()
 
    context = {
        'title': "Магазин",
        'footer_1': "127015, Москва, Бумажный пр-д., д. 14, стр. 2 ООО «НИКАМЕД».",
        'footer_2': "Копирование материалов запрещено.",
        'products': Product.objects.all(),
        'sizes': Size.objects.all(),
        'article_size': ArticleSize.objects.all(),
        'form': form,
 
    }
    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
 
def basket_add(request,product,size):
    product = Product.objects.get(article=product)
    size = ArticleSize.objects.get(article_size=size)
    basket = Basket.objects.filter(user=request.user,product=product,size=size)
 
    if not basket.exists():
        Basket.objects.create(user=request.user,product=product,qty=1,size=size)
    else:
        basket = basket.last()
        basket.qty += 1
        basket.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="goods-group">
                   {% for product in products %}
                       <div class="goods">
                               <div class="shoe-photo">
                                   <a href="{% url 'products:item_info' %}">
                                        <img src="{{ product.img.url }}" alt="нет фото">
                                   </a>
                                   <a href="#">
                                        <svg class="photo-heart" fill="#C0BFBF" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"><title></title><path d="M171.28,41.69a48.29,48.29,0,0,0-68.5,0l-2.5,3-2.5-2.5a48.29,48.29,0,0,0-68.5,0c-19,18.5-19,49-1,68l50,53a29.92,29.92,0,0,0,43.5,0l50.5-53.5c17.5-19.5,17-49.5-1-68Zm-14,53.5-50.5,53.5a10.26,10.26,0,0,1-14.5,0l-50-53c-10.5-11.5-10.5-29,.5-40s29-11,40.5,0l2.5,2.5c8,8,20.5,8,28,0l2.5-2.5a28.37,28.37,0,0,1,40,0,27.78,27.78,0,0,1,1,39.5Z"></path></g></svg>
                                   </a>
                                </div>
 
                           <a href="#">
                                <div class="price">{{product.price}} руб</div>
                           </a>
                           <a href="#">
                                <div class="description">{{product.description}}</div>
 
                           </a>
 
                           <div class="sizes-group">
                                   <form action="" method="post">
                                       {% for item in sizes %}
                                           {% if item.article == product.article %}
                                                {% for size in article_size %}
                                                    {% if size.to_article == item.article %}
                                                           <label>
                                                               {{form.checkbox_size}}
                                                               <span class="title_checkbox">{{size.size_name}}</span>
                                                           </label>
                                                    {% else %}
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                           {% else %}
                                           {% endif %}
                                       {% endfor %}
                                   </form>
                           </div>
 
                           <a href="{% url 'products:basket_add' product=product.article size=product.sizes.article_size %}">
                               <button class="btn" type="submit">
                                   <svg class="button-cart" fill="#C0BFBF" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="-2 -2 204.00 204.00" data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"><title></title><path d="M183.25,52.75a18.22,18.22,0,0,0-7-1h-91c-3.5,0-8-.5-11.5.5a9.64,9.64,0,0,0-7.5,9.5,10,10,0,0,0,10,10h90.5l-8,42a10.22,10.22,0,0,1-10,8h-75a10.66,10.66,0,0,1-10-8l-16-74a20.3,20.3,0,0,0-19.5-16h-7a10,10,0,0,0,0,20h7l16,74c3,14,15,23.5,29.5,23.5h75c12,0,24.5-8,28-19.5,2.5-8,4-17,5.5-25,1.5-8.5,3.5-17,5-25a17.76,17.76,0,0,0,1-5,17,17,0,0,0,.5-5c0-4-2-8-5.5-9Zm-132,108.5a15,15,0,0,0,30,0h0a15,15,0,0,0-30,0Zm90,0a15,15,0,1,0,15-15,15,15,0,0,0-15,15v0Z"></path></g></svg>
                                   В корзину</button>
                           </a>
                       </div>
                   {% endfor %}
               </div>
           </div>
```

Tell me how such problems are solved? Maybe I’m moving in the wrong direction and I need to rewrite everything?

Sorry for the confusion, I’m ready to clarify everything that is necessary.

Thanks in advance everyone!

I try to send in to view product with selected size.

Comment: I corrected the code a little, now everything works, well, it almost works. If I hardcode data about the size object from the template in the view, then everything is ok, but if I just try to get the value from request.POST.get('size'), then I always get None.

Here are the corrected models, template and view.

Models:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. If some one interested, please let me know and I will write solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code a little, now everything works, well, it almost works. If I hardcode data about the size object from the template in the view, then everything is ok, but if I just try to get the value from request.POST.get('size'), then I always get None.

Here are the corrected models, template and view.

Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
article = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,blank=False,unique=True,primary_key=True)
img = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images')
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,blank=False)
is_child = models.BooleanField(null=False)
season = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False)
color = models.CharField(max_length=24,null=False)
sizes = models.ForeignKey(to='Size',on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article_size')

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.article}"
```

class Size(models.Model):
article_size = models.CharField(max_length=12,null=False,unique=True,primary_key=True)
size_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False, blank=False)
qty = models.SmallIntegerField()
to_article = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False)

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.article_size}"
```

class Basket(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(to=Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article')
size = models.ForeignKey(to=Size,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='article_size')
qty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
create_time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def **str**(self):
return f"Корзина для {self.user.email} товар {self.product.article},размер {self.size.size_name}"

Template:

```
<div class="goods-group">
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="goods">
            <div class="shoe-photo">
                <a href="{% url 'products:item_info' %}">
                    <img src="{{ product.img.url }}" alt="нет фото">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class="photo-heart" fill="#C0BFBF" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
                         data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
                        <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
                        <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"><title></title>
                            <path d="M171.28,41.69a48.29,48.29,0,0,0-68.5,0l-2.5,3-2.5-2.5a48.29,48.29,0,0,0-68.5,0c-19,18.5-19,49-1,68l50,53a29.92,29.92,0,0,0,43.5,0l50.5-53.5c17.5-19.5,17-49.5-1-68Zm-14,53.5-50.5,53.5a10.26,10.26,0,0,1-14.5,0l-50-53c-10.5-11.5-10.5-29,.5-40s29-11,40.5,0l2.5,2.5c8,8,20.5,8,28,0l2.5-2.5a28.37,28.37,0,0,1,40,0,27.78,27.78,0,0,1,1,39.5Z"></path>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>

            <a href="#">
                <div class="price">{{product.price}} руб</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="description">{{product.description}}</div>

            </a>

            <div class="sizes-group">
                <form id="size_checkbox_form" action="/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for size in sizes %}
                        {% if product.article == size.to_article %}
                            <label>
                                <input class="size_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="{{size}}" value="{{size}}">
                                <span class="title_checkbox">{{size.size_name}}</span>
                            </label>
                        {%endif%}
                    {% endfor %}
                </form>
            </div>
                <button   form="size_checkbox_form" formaction="{% url 'products:basket_add' product.article %}" class="btn" type="submit" >
                    <svg class="button-cart" fill="#C0BFBF" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="-2 -2 204.00 204.00"
                         data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g>
                        <g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g>
                        <g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"><title></title>
                            <path d="M183.25,52.75a18.22,18.22,0,0,0-7-1h-91c-3.5,0-8-.5-11.5.5a9.64,9.64,0,0,0-7.5,9.5,10,10,0,0,0,10,10h90.5l-8,42a10.22,10.22,0,0,1-10,8h-75a10.66,10.66,0,0,1-10-8l-16-74a20.3,20.3,0,0,0-19.5-16h-7a10,10,0,0,0,0,20h7l16,74c3,14,15,23.5,29.5,23.5h75c12,0,24.5-8,28-19.5,2.5-8,4-17,5.5-25,1.5-8.5,3.5-17,5-25a17.76,17.76,0,0,0,1-5,17,17,0,0,0,.5-5c0-4-2-8-5.5-9Zm-132,108.5a15,15,0,0,0,30,0h0a15,15,0,0,0-30,0Zm90,0a15,15,0,1,0,15-15,15,15,0,0,0-15,15v0Z"></path>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                    В корзину
                </button>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

View:

```
Does anyone know why None appears when submitting a button? Maybe I forgot to specify an attribute?
```

Thank you.

Does anyone know why None appears when submitting a button? Maybe I forgot to specify an attribute?

Thank you.